# Jamaican influence on late 90s Cash Money music?

Tags: rap

Some of the rappers from the late 90s Cash Money Records albums have vocal styles that sound Jamaican, despite them being from New Orleans. [One track](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=n6Npm1FNhbk) from Juvenile's 400 Degreez album actually features a guest spot from "Papa Reu" who sounds thoroughly Jamaican.

Question: What is the relationship between the Jamaican dialect and New Orleans, particularly in this context?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's more of a general Caribbean connection than Jamaican.

The Carribean has, and continues to play a [significant role](https://gonola.com/things-to-do-in-new-orleans/the-caribbean-connection-nola-meets-the-islands) in many aspects (including music) of New Orleans area culture. Haiti probably plays a larger role than most, but many parts of the Caribbean contribute.

[Papa Reu himself is from Trinidad & Tobago](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Papa_Reu) (not Jamaica).

So, catching a Caribbean "feel" from New Orleans arts, language, cuisine, etc. would not be surprising, and in fact, should likely be expected.

Comment: wow, "the northern-most city in the Caribbean" is great. Thanks for sharing.